# Bilinear form is bounded

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, bilinear-form

$\newcommand{\ints}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{ \lVert #1 \rVert }$
Given a bilinear form $a(x,y) = \sum_{n\in\ints}\sum_{m\in\ints}v_m  x_{n-m} y_n$.

$x \in \ell^2$, $y \in \ell^2$, $v \in \ell^1$

I want to show that it is bounded, $|a(x,y)|\leq C \lVert x \rVert \lVert y \rVert$.

How can I show this? Should it be that $|a(x,y)|\leq \norm{v} \norm{x} \norm{y}$?

Comment: Yes. The thing with $y$ is immediate from the Cauchy-Boun'akovskij-Schwarz inequality, so it remains to see that $v\ast x \in \ell^2$ and $\lVert v\ast x\rVert \leqslant \lVert v\rVert\,\lVert x\rVert$.

Comment: I am confused about notation here. How I can represent $v$ and $x$ as a something separate from $a(x,y)$?

Comment: $x$ is the sequence $(... ,x_{-1},x_0,x_1,...)$, and its $\ell^2$ norm is $\sqrt{\sum\limits_n |x_n|^2}$, right?

Comment: Sorry. By $v\ast x$ I denote the convolution of $v$ and $x$, $$(v\ast x)_n = \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} v_m x_{n-m}.$$ You can see that $a(x,y) = \langle v\ast x, y\rangle$, I suppose.

Comment: I can see that now thank you. Is the term convolution and the notation $v*x$ reserved for $\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z} } v_m x_{n-m}$ type sums? Is there a generalisation for something like this in terms of linear maps, say if we had $\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z} } v_m x_{n-2m}$. Is there a way to say something then about $v$ and $x$ independent of the bilinear form $a$ to get our bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $\|u\|_2 \le 1$ and $\|v\|_2 \le 1$. Then
\begin{align}
         2|v_m x_{n-m}u_n| & = 2|v_m||x_{n-m}|^{1/2}|x_{n-m}|^{1/2}|u_n| \\
       & \le |v_m|^2|x_{n-m}| + |x_{n-m}||u_n|^2
\end{align}
Now sum over $n$ and $m$. Sum the first set of terms on the right in $n$ first, and sum the second set of terms on the right in $m$ first. That gives
\begin{align}
  2\sum_{n,m}|v_m||x_{n-m}||u_n|
    & \le \sum_{m}|v_m|^2\sum_{n}|x_{n-m}|+\sum_{n}|u_n|^2\sum_{m}|x_{n-m}| \\
    & \le 2\|x\|_1
\end{align}
For $\|u\|_2 \ne 0$ and $\|v\|_2 \ne 0$, you can replace $\{v_m \}$ with $\{v_m/\|v\|_2\}$ and $\{ u_n \}$ with $\{ u_n/\|u\|_2\}$ in order to obtain
$$
       \sum_{n,m}|v_m x_{n-m} u_{n}| \le \|x\|_1 \|u\|_2\|v\|_2.
$$